# Powermock and FileUtils package

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Can we mock the static methods of FileUtils package using PowerMock ? I have a requirement where my business code call a copyFileToURL(url,file) of FileUtils package and for unit testing I have to mock it using Powermock which gives unfinished stubbing exception.

This link [org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException Unfinished stubbing detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437313/org-mockito-exceptions-misusing-unfinishedstubbingexception-unfinished-stubbing) , it is suggested that we cannot mock the classes of java.lang package to which these file utils belong? I do not want to create wrapper around this class. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read that linked question carefully, you find:

> I cannot mock classes in from java.lang, java.net, java.io or other system classes, why?

But you intend to use the Apache Commons FileUtil class [method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File)).

In that sense: you want to mock a static "commons or garden" method.

And if that doesn't work: you are doing it wrong. So, simple answer: read their [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) again; and check where your code is deviating.

But beyond that: using static always means: as it leads to tight coupling of your production code; and you loose the advantages of polymorphism. And it means: you are restricted in the mocking framework you can use (as only PowerMock or JMockit support static mocking).

Thus my real answer: spent those few lines, and built a wrapper around that static methods; and get rid of the requirement to mock static calls.